# SQL calcular dias transcurridos entre 2 registros de una misma tabla

Tags: mysql, sqlite, mssql

necesito obtener los dias trascurridos entre las fechas de los registros de una misma tabla:

Tengo esta consulta

```
Select  Commnet_id, Ticket_id, Creator_User, Comment_txt, Commnet_Date
From    Comments 
Where   Ticket_id = 9988
```

y obtengo este resultado

```
Commnet_id     Ticket_id    Creator_User    Comment_txt         updated_at              
30083           6403        User900         "Help commnet"      2021-04-23 17:34:37     
29876           6403        SysHLPDSK       "SOS comment"       2021-03-19 08:41:42     
29866           6403        User900         "Error commnet"     2021-03-19 08:18:32
```

Pero necesito saber la cantidad de dias transcurridos entre las fechas "update_at" y obtener estos resultados en una columna llamada por ejemplo "**DateDiff**":

```
Commnet_id     Ticket_id    Creator_User    Comment_txt         updated_at              DateDiff
30083           6403        User900         "Help commnet"      2021-04-23 17:34:37     35
29876           6403        SysHLPDSK       "SOS comment"       2021-03-19 08:41:42     0
29866           6403        User900         "Error commnet"     2021-03-19 08:18:32 

--
```

Comment: ¿Sería la diferencia entre la fecha máxima y mínima? ¿O es la diferencia de una fila a la siguiente?

Comment: Cuales son tus campos fecha

Comment: @PatricioMoracho la diferencia que necesito es entre la un registro y el siguiente.

Comment: @Japv el campo fecha es el Updated_At.
o sea, lo que necesito es que en la columna DateDiff, necesito mostrar los dias transcurridos entre el registro commet_id 30083 y el 29876.
espero haber sido claro.

Answer (score 0):

Seria asi:

Select  Commnet_id, Ticket_id, Creator_User, Comment_txt, Commnet_Date
,ISNULL(DATEDIFF(DAY, LAG(Commnet_Date)
over (PARTITION BY  Ticket_id order by Commnet_Date), Commnet_Date),0) as DateDiff
From    Comments
Where   Ticket_id = 6403
order by Ticket_id, Commnet_Date

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Pude encontrar la solución:

```
Select Commnet_id, Ticket_id,T Creator_User, TComment_txt, Commnet_Date, DATEDIFF(dd,fec_emi,GETDATE()) as DATEDIFF From Comments
```

Comment: Por favor elabora una respuesta explicando los que no funciona de tu enfoque inicial y cómo el nuevo enfoque lo resuelve.